# a strange mistake in rm file

Tags: linux, bash

I need to delete some files in a directory using a list. For example I have this file list:

```
list.txt:

0NM.pdb
POR.pdb
0UA.pdb
AU7.pdb
```

In `/home/my_directory/` I have this file

```
U6Y.pdb
0NM.pdb
POR.pdb
AR2.pdb
0UA.pdb
AU7.pdb
```

At the end in the directory i should have only this:

```
U6Y.pdb
AR2.pdb
```

I have show some other discussion for this problem and I try to use some different script but all gave me the same result:

```
rm: impossibile rimuovere "ONM.pdb\r": File o directory non esistente
rm: impossibile rimuovere "POR.pdb\r": File o directory non esistente
rm: impossibile rimuovere "OUA.pdb\r": File o directory non esistente
rm: impossibile rimuovere "AU7.pdb\r": File o directory non esistente
```

I try to use these different script:

-> `printf "%s\n" $(<list.txt) | xargs -I@ rm @`

-> `while read name; do  rm "$name"; done < /home/list.txt`

-> `while read -r filename; do   rm "$filename"; done </home/list.txt`

-> `xargs -a /home/list.txt -d'\n' rm`

Why all these give me the same error? Why does `"\r"` appear at the end of the file names to be deleted?

Comment: It seems like the list is created with windows?
Can you may exchange the end of line characters?

Comment: How I can do that? I use the comand "chmod +x list.txt" but I have the same result

Comment: Try running [`dos2unix`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) on the `list.txt` before running the `rm` commands

Comment: OK! Thanks, now thwe script works well!

Comment: yes, `dos2unix list.txt` should solve this problem. Voting to close as a typo. If you going to continue to use `bash`, please book mark https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info  and review often the section labeled *Before asking about problematic code*. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newline character in Windows is `\r\n`, and in Linux is `\n`. Linux cannot recognize the `\r` identifier and will treat it as part of the text content.

You can use [`dos2unix`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) to convert it permanently (`dos2unix list.txt`) or you could do it on the fly by setting `IFS=$'\r'`:

Example:

```
while IFS=$'\r' read -r filename || [[ $filename ]]
do
    echo "do something with $filename"
done < list.txt
```

Comment: Mention how to use the `dos2unix` or some alternative command to fix this issue. Possibly recreate one of the scripts OP tried to use with your fix included.

Comment: If you use `IFS=$'\r'`, then you don't need the `dos2unix`; IFS characters on the end of your string get stripped by `read`. (I don't advise having spaces or tabs in IFS in this context: If a filename _really has_ trailing spaces, it's a bug to not be able to read it from your data file).

Comment: @TedLyngmo, what "new version"? You get that ("that" being compatibility with both text file formats) even with `IFS=$'\r' read -r filename; do ...; done <list.txt`, with no `dos2unix` anywhere.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, ...and having `IFS=$'\n'` is completely pointless. `$'\n'` is the default argument to `read -d`, telling it what character to _stop reading at_ if `-d` isn't overridden. The thing it stops reading at can't possibly show up inside a record, so it'll never show up when the record is being broken down into fields.

Comment: Actually, let me revise that. `while IFS=$'\r' read -r filename || [[ $filename ]]; do ...; done <list.txt` would be more strongly compatible with DOS files, which aren't required to have a trailing newline.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I just noticed that when creating a dos file with notepad :) Did I get it right this time?

Comment: Yup, looks good to me.